# How to count setof / number of keys of JSON in postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column in `jsonb` storing a map, like `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}` where the number of keys is different in each row.

I want to count it --  jsonb_object_keys can retrieve the keys but it is in `setof`

Are there something like this?

```
(select count(jsonb_object_keys(obj) from XXX )
```

(this won't work as `ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`)

[Postgres JSON Functions and Operators Document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

```
json_object_keys(json)
jsonb_object_keys(jsonb)

setof text  Returns set of keys in the outermost JSON object.
json_object_keys('{"f1":"abc","f2":{"f3":"a", "f4":"b"}}')  

json_object_keys
------------------
f1
f2
```

Crosstab isn't feasible as the number of key could be large.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could convert keys to array and use array_length to get this:

```
select array_length(array_agg(A.key), 1) from (
    select json_object_keys('{"f1":"abc","f2":{"f3":"a", "f4":"b"}}') as key
) A;
```

If you need to get this for the whole table, you can just group by primary key.

Comment: I'm getting `function json_object_keys(character varying) does not exist 
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.;`

Comment: Thanks @LeDroid, I actually use Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 37):

Shortest:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM jsonb_object_keys('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb);
```

Returns 3

If you want all json number of keys from a table, it gives:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jsonb_object_keys(myJsonField)) nbr_keys FROM myTable;
```

Edit: there was a typo in the second example.

Comment: I'm getting `function json_object_keys(character varying) does not exist 
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.;`

Comment: @ericn I used pg v12 i think, which version do you use?

Comment: @ericn Do "select version();" on Amazon Redshift to get PG version. In the doc they say it doesn't support all 9.x feature and Json implementation is one of them. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VERSION.html

Answer (score 5):

While a sub select must be used to convert the JSON keys set to rows, the following tweaked query might run faster by skipping building the temporary array:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM
   (SELECT jsonb_object_keys('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb)) v;
```

and it's a bit shorter ;)

To make it a function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.count_jsonb_keys(j jsonb)
  RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT count(*) from (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(j)) v;
$function$
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternately, you could simply return the upper bounds of the keys when listed as an array:

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_UPPER( -- Grab the upper bounds of the array
        ARRAY( -- Convert rows into an array.
            SELECT JSONB_OBJECT_KEYS(obj)
        ),
        1 -- The array's dimension we're interested in retrieving the count for
    ) AS count
FROM
    xxx
```

Using `'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb` as obj, count would result in a value of three (3).

Pasteable example:

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_UPPER( -- Grab the upper bounds of the array
        ARRAY( -- Convert rows into an array.
             SELECT JSONB_OBJECT_KEYS('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb)
        ),
        1 -- The array's dimension we're interested in retrieving the count for
    ) AS count
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the effort, you can define a function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_map_length(json) RETURNS integer AS
$$ SELECT array_length(array_agg(A.key), 1) FROM (
  SELECT json_object_keys($1) as key
) A; $$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```