# Django queryset grouped by count of values in Postgres JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql

My model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Image(models.Model):
    tags = JSONField(null=False, blank=True, default={})
```

tags field value can be empty, or something like:

```
[
   {"tag": "xxx"}, 
   {"tag": "yyy"},
   {"tag": "zzz"}
]
```

The number or dicts may vary (from 0 to N).

I need to make a query that counts Images grouped by number of tags. Something like:

```
{
   "0": "345",
   "1": "1223",
   "2": "220",
   ...
   "N": "23"
}
```

where the key is the number of tags, and the value is the count of Image objects that contains this number of tags.

How can i do that? Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

I modified my code: now I don't use JsonField, but a dedicated model:

```
class ImageTag(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    tag = models.CharField()
```

The question is the same :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the high level ORM API. However you should be able to build something with either `extra()` or raw querysets and the ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171737/how-to-count-setof-number-of-keys-of-json-in-postgresql).

Comment: Also, you probably should read [PostgreSQL anti-pattern: unnecessary json columns](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/). Most notably, *“PostgreSQL has json support but you shouldn’t use it for the great majority of what you’re doing […] as it’ll make querying and manipulating it harder.”*

Comment: I expose a subset of information I store in this jsonfield; thank you always for the interesting read :)